# gitlab empty response from server while clonning repository

Tags: git, http, command-line-interface, gitlab, git-clone

I just installed gitlab server and it is running with default configuration, I created a public visibility project called `test` and I went to another machine on the same network and tried to clone it but I keep getting the error

```
    developer@ItnowDev:/apps/html$ git clone http://IP-OF-SERVER/USER/test.git
Cloning into 'test'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://IP-OF-SERVER/USER/test.git/': Empty reply from server
```

I am using 2.9.0 git to connect to gitlab server and the gitlab server is using http port, I can reach the gitlab server through my web browser but cannot do it on cli, what am I missing? does cli uses any other port protocol that could be blocked by firewalls?

Comment: Could it be https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/2522#issuecomment-27605028 (server listening only on localhost)